Нужно записать список из строк с тире в файл
Есть 2 списка. Один получается записать, другой нет, по всей видимости дело в тире.
import json


data = {
  'list_kukoin': ["ZEC-USDT", 'VR-USDT', 'UXLINK-USDT', 'RUNE-USDT', 'BCH-USDT']
'list_HTX' : ['zecusdt', 'vrusdt', 'uxlinkusdt', 'runeusdt', 'bchusdt']  
}
def write_list():
    with open('symbols.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)
write_list()


запятую поставьте, что ли. между элементами словаря...

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, и вы хотите записать в файл только список с тире, то измените функцию write_list, и поставьте , между элементами словаря
измените строку в функции write_list : json.dump(data['list_kukoin'], json_file)
